# How should I reference a message from a mailing list?

Tags: biblatex

What should the BibLaTeX entry for a message from a mailing list look like? For example, the following message by Linus Torvalds from the Linux kernel mailing list: https://lkml.org/lkml/2005/4/10/70.

Comment: `@online` or `@misc`. You have a '`title`', an `author` and a `date` as well as a `url`, that should be enough for the two types.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `@online` or `@misc` entry types both seem appropriate.

You have a `title`, an `author` and a `date` and you can also give the `url` (`urldate` if you must). If you want to give more info you could add `note = {Message to the Linux kernel mailing list}` or similar.